# normalization of categorical variable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a dataset which contains gender as Male and Female. I have converted male to 1 and female to 0 using pandas functionality which has now data type int8. now I wanted to normalize columns such as weight and height. So what should be done with the gender column: should it be normalized or not. I am planning to use it in for a linear regression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I think you are mixing up normalization with standardization.

**Normalization:**

rescales your data into a range of [0;1]

**Standardization:**

rescales your data to have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.

**Back to your question:**

For your gender column your points are already ranging between 0 and 1. Therefore your data is already "normalized". So your question should be if you can standarize your data and the answer is: yes you could, but it doesn't really make sense. This question was already discussed here: [Should you ever standardise binary variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59392/should-you-ever-standardise-binary-variables)

Comment: I read answer on cross-validated but unable to understand. I am using linear regression from scikit-learn please tell me specifically what should I do in my case. I mean i should standardise it or not. and whats effect of it on rmse.

Comment: The answer is you shouldn't standardize your gender column

Comment: how about if there were more categories ?